# onUploadStart Event of Uploadify v 2.1.4 is not triggered

Tags: uploadify

Subject says it. It fires onComplete Event but not the onUploadStart event.  Here is the code snippet:

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
            'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/Content/uploadify-v2.1.4/uploadify.swf")',
            'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/Content/uploadify-v2.1.4/cancel.png")',
            'buttonText': 'Select Photos',
            'script': '/controller/action',
            'folder': 'SomeFolder',
            'scriptData': { AuthenticationToken: "@auth" },
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true,
            'queueID': 'file_queue',
            'queueSizeLimit': 5,
            'sizeLimit': 4194304,
            'onUploadStart': function () {
                alert("Upload Starting");
            },
            'onComplete': uploadComplete

        });
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but I wanted to post my fix in case someone is ever in the spot I was in.  The version of uploadify I was using was not calling the onUploadStart event at all.  Either check that your version makes the call, or add this to the uploadfile event:

```
     if (typeof settings.onUploadStart === 'function') {
          settings.onUploadStart.call($this, file);
     }
```